# Serial data,scan data from database and return true if found c#

Tags: c#

*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Data.SQLite;
namespace Datalogging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class ThreadExample
    {
        public static void ThreadJob()
        {
            string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\johnmark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\employee.sqlite;";
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
            //open connection to database
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Select empID from EmployeeList", sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader reader;
                reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(definition.buffering, reader.GetValue(0))));
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Text);
                        //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text)));
                    }
                }
                sqliteCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        //string received_data;
        //Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob));
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Port");
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)button2.Content == "Connect")
                {
                    string myItem = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (myItem == "Select Port")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Select Port");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serial.PortName = myItem;
                        serial.Open();
                        button2.Content = "Disconnect";
                        textbox2.Text = "Serial Port Opened";
                        serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    serial.Close();
                    button2.Content = "Connect";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        #region Receiving
        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
            definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(definition.buffering);
            Console.WriteLine();
            thread.Start();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

*

Hello guys.

Can you help me debug this?

If I send a 13 bytes data twice, this error will appear.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in 
mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `port_DataReceived` I presume will be called each time a buffer of data is received from the port.  First time it will start the thread, thread will run through, exit, and at that point thread is done and gone.  Second time `port_dataReceived` is called, it'll try to `Start()` a thread that is already done and gone, and hence you get that exception.

Your options is either to post a work item to a thread pool, or create and start a new thread in `port_dataReceived` rather than create thread when window is created.

E.g.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Data.SQLite;
namespace Datalogging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class ThreadExample
    {
        public static void ThreadJob()
        {
            string dBConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\Users\johnmark\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SerialTrial\SerialTrial\bin\Debug\employee.sqlite;";
            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dBConnectionString);
            //open connection to database
            try
            {
                sqliteCon.Open();
                SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand("Select empID from EmployeeList", sqliteCon);
                SQLiteDataReader reader;
                reader = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
                //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Clear();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string Text = (String.Format("{0}", Object.Equals(definition.buffering, reader.GetValue(0))));
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Text);
                        //richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text)));
                    }
                }
                sqliteCon.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        //string received_data;
        //Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            combobox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select Port");
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string[] ports = null;
            ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            // Display each port name to the console. 
            int c = ports.Count();
            for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++)
            {
                if (!combobox1.Items.Contains(ports[i - 1]))
                {
                    combobox1.Items.Add(ports[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((string)button2.Content == "Connect")
                {
                    string myItem = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    if (myItem == "Select Port")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Select Port");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serial.PortName = myItem;
                        serial.Open();
                        button2.Content = "Disconnect";
                        textbox2.Text = "Serial Port Opened";
                        serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    serial.Close();
                    button2.Content = "Connect";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


        #region Receiving
        public void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytes = serial.BytesToRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
            serial.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
            foreach (var item in buffer)
            {
                Console.Write(item.ToString());
            }
            definition.buffering = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(definition.buffering);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadExample.ThreadJob));
            thread.Start();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit the code and post the edited one in your comment please?  Since I am a novice in c#. This is my first time coding it. thanks

Comment: your edited code has this error:
Error 2 'Datalogging.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'combobox1_SelectionChanged' and no extension method 'combobox1_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Datalogging.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Datalogging\Datalogging\MainWindow.xaml 14 110 Datalogging

Comment: Oops, I removed an empty function to clean up the code not realizing you may have it referenced somewhere else.  Just put that one back in, or remove reference from your XAML as it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Opps. I have another question. How can I make the serial(SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();) global so that I can access it and put it in this if function:
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Text))
                    {  
                        //I am planning to put serial.Write(); here
                        Console.WriteLine(Text);

                    }

Comment: You can pass it as parameter to your new thread.  Look into `ParameterizedThreadStart` class for more info.

Comment: can you enlighten me with it? newbie here. hehe

Comment: Take a look at an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459(v=vs.110).aspx).